# Making a Discord Bot in JavaScript: Attempting to make a game of wordchain between two players

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, bots, discord.js

The user that uses a particular command 'shiritori' and tags another user will be player1. The tagged user will be player2. I have already downloaded a JSON file with most dictionary words so firstly and I have tested it here and it appeared to be successful:

```
let usedWords = []
let points = 0

function shiritoriCommand(arguments, receivedMessage) {
    let word = receivedMessage.content.substr(11)
    fs.readFile('./words_dictionary.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error reading file from disk:", err)
                return
            }
            try {
                const dictionary = JSON.parse(jsonString)
                if (word in dictionary && !(usedWords.includes(word)) && word.length >= 4) {
                    points = points + word.length
                    receivedMessage.channel.send('The word is in the dictionary! You have a total of ' + points + ' points!')
                    usedWords.push(word)
                } else {
                    receivedMessage.channel.send('Either the word is not in the dictionary, it is too short or it has already been used. You gain no points.')
                }
        } catch(err) {
                console.log('Error parsing JSON string:', err)
            }
        })

}
```

The current program takes in the received message and separates the word with the substr(). Then it reads the dictionary to see if the word is found in there. If it is, it pushes the word into the array of used words so it cannot be used again to gain points. The points are the word length (which has to be 4 or more otherwise it will be disregarded.) The total is shown when a valid word is used.

However, I am finding it challenging to incorporate 2 players into it. I was inspired by the Pokecord duel, how does one differentiate between the two players' words and what exactly must be done? I initially arranged it like this:

```
let player1 = receivedMessage.author
let player2 = receivedMessage.mentions.members.first()
```

On top of that, I want each player to have a 15 second timeslot. The game stops when either player has 200 points. Now I can manage that with a while loop:

```
points1 = 0
points2 = 0

while (points1 <= 200 || points2 <= 200) {
/* Do I use set interval and duplicate the first function for each player
 and assign their respective points */
}
```

If they do not answer by then, then the turn goes to the next player. I have no clue how to combine all of this to make a valid game.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to figure out a way to keep track of which player's turn it is. In this case you could use a boolean, as there are only two players. If you want the game to be more extensible, you'll obviously need to use a different logical check.

In this case, if

```
(player1Turn === true) {
// do some stuff
}
```

Of course this is just one way to handle it